# How to add columns to the User Tasks Web Part?

Tags: web-part, column, tasks

I want to add some columns to the User Tasks Web Part. I use WSS 3.0.

Is it possible to add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This web part has essentially no configuration, and additional columns can't be added I'm afraid. Your options are:

1. Upgrade to SharePoint Standard and use the Content Query Web Part.
2. Purchase a third party tool (search for something like 'list rollup web part' for options)
3. Custom develop a solution